# Is there something like "follow this question"?

Tags: support

When I find a interesting question asked by others, so I want to know what's the answer. However, this question has not been answered (or get a satisfactory answer), i want to know "follow" this question when there are new answers provided. So, this is my question! thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The "favorite question" option (this star under voting arrows) is the closest to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Favorites are probably a good solution, but RSS feeds (and each question has one) are probably another alternative. Recently they have been updating the feeds based on edited content (e.g. a new answer added, an answer or the question edited). So you wouldn't know if a question has an accepted answer, but you would know if anybody has added anything new.